# Toggle column headers extjs grid panel

Tags: extjs, header, grid

I am a newbie to ExtJS.I am now working on grids.I would like to toggle the visibility of the headers on a button click(Show and hide the header only).Any suggestions should be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
var el = myDataGrid.headerCt.getEl();
if (el.isVisible()) {
    el.hide();
} else {
    el.show();
}
```

If you want to hide all headers in all grids, I suggest you assign them some custom class and then you do the above for all of them separatelly.

Something along the following lines (not tested)

```
var allGrids = Ext.dom.Query.select(".myDataGrids");
Ext.Array.each(allGrids, function(gridDomElement, index) {
    var el = Ext.fly(gridDomElement);
    // Do the above 
    // ....
});
```

Comment: I appreciate you for your effort.I would like to express my gratitude.Thanks a lot.